# Cannot create a consistent method resolution.. Why?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am getting error in multiple inheritance. As I am new in python so I did not getting why I am unable to do so.

```
class A(object):
    def say_hello(self):
        print 'A says hello'


class B(A):
    def say_hello(self):
        super(B, self).say_hello()
        print 'B says hello'

class C(A):
    def say_hello(self):
        super(C, self).say_hello()
        print 'C says hello'

class D(A, B):
    def say_hello(self):
        super(D, self).say_hello()
        print 'D says hello'

DD = D()
DD.say_hello()
```

I am getting Error:-  Cannot create a consistent method resolution.. Why?

Comment: Not causing this issue, but the convention is to use *self* for 1st arg to instance tnods and *cls* in class methods.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the super call in B?  Mind you, dunno if that matters by the time you get to B.

Comment: see also MRO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [metaclass multiple inheritance inconsistency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003053/metaclass-multiple-inheritance-inconsistency)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`D` inherits `A` **and** `B` and **both** have a function `say_hello`. And `B` inherits from `A`.

You can't multiply inherit from a base class followed by a derived class
It's impossible to define a consistent MRO that satisfies the usual MRO constraints/guarantees. As described [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

You now call `super(D, self).say_hello()` and python does not know which `say_hello` to pick.
`A` or `B`?!

This as example would work:

```
class D(A): #D only inherits A not A and B
    def say_hello(self):
        super(D, self).say_hello()
        print 'D says hello'


DD = D()
DD.say_hello()

#output
>>>A says hello
>>>D says hello


#There are 2 connections to As say_hello
    A-----
   / \   |
  B   C  |
  |     /
  \    / 
    D
```

PS: Please use "self" as name for the first parameter

**Update:**
It would pick `As` say_hello if the inheritance would look something like this

```
class A(object):
    def say_hello(cls):
        print 'A says hello'


class B():
     def say_hello(cls):
        print 'B says hello'


class C(B):
    def say_hello(cls):
        super(C, cls).say_hello()
        print 'C says hello'


class D(A, C):
    def say_hello(self):
        super(D, self).say_hello()
        print 'D says hello'


DD = D()
DD.say_hello()
```

Inheritance-tree:

```
    A
  /
  |   B
  |   |
  |   C
  \   / 
    D
```

Python now picks the say_hello with the least specialization e.g. A.

Comment: Wouldn't it pick A because it is the earlier base with the method?

Comment: @JLPeyret i am sorry, I do not understand your question. Of course he will call As `say_hello`

Comment: But you did not answer his question you just removed multiple inheritance. My question was in regards to your 'python does not know' sentence. I think it would pick A as per OPs question, except I suspect B calling A itself might confuse it.

Comment: I think same.. JL Peyret

Comment: Have you read through the link I provided? There is a very detailed explanation on how inheritance-trees are build and when this fails.

Comment: It shouldn't pick it because it's the least specialized. It should pick it because it's the first in the left to right order of inheritance of `D(A,C)`

Comment: @Cobertos: I think the point being made is *if* this was allowed, it would be picking the least specialized version; the *reason* is, as you say, because it's listed first, but the problem there is that, reasonably, when `C` asks to invoke a `super()` method, it expects that 1) `A`'s method has not yet been called, and 2) `A`s method will eventually be called (as long as all other classes in the chain cooperatively delegate via `super()` as well). If `A`'s method is invoked *first*, even if it call's `super()` to invoke the others, it's too late; the order of invocation invariants are broken.