# Why can't incorrect MRO not be detected by a static type checker like mypy?

Tags: python-3.x, generics, mypy, python-typing, method-resolution-order

Consider the following scenario:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class HasFoo(Protocol):
    foo: str


class Mixin(HasFoo):
    foo = "test"


@dataclass()
class MyClass(Generic[T], Mixin):
    t: T
```

If you execute this code, you get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/veith/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.2/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 16, in <module>
    class MyClass(Generic[T], FooMixin):
  File "/home/veith/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 85, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Generic, Mixin

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I guess this has something to do with the fact that Protocol can also take generic arguments like this:

```py
class HasT(Protocol[T]):
    t: T

# sugar for
class HasT(Protocol, Generic[T]):
    t: T

# also works like this, which I would have expected to cause the same issue, but doesn't
class HasT(Generic[T], Protocol):
    t: T
```

[I could not find info on this in the PEP for protocols.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#generic-protocols)

The answer to make it work is actually rather simple:
Just reverse the order of inheritance in your code, so it looks like this:

```py
@dataclass()
class MyClass(Mixin, Generic[T]):
    t: T
```

So why is this happening, and why does it type-check using mypy 0.980?
[The linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060734/cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-why) does not answer my question about why it type-checks.
`Generic` inherits nothing, and `Protocol` inherits `Generic`.
So I see how the inheritance "tree" has a loop, but why does mypy not recognize this?

Comment: Short version: `FooMixin` inherits from `Generic` (because `Protocol` does too). The rules for constructing a consistent MRO don't allow you to multiply inherit from a base class before the derived class; when a derived class invokes `super().method`, it "knows" that the base class version will be invoked after it, but if you say the base class takes precedence (by listing it first) the base class version must be invoked first, *then* the derived (if the base uses `super()`); the contradiction can't be resolved. The duplicate covers this in greater detail (it's not specific to `Generic`).

Comment: I understand that, but it seems like a static type checker would be able to catch this, but doesn't. Why?

Comment: It probably could, they just didn't add that as a feature. The inheritance described violates MRO rules, but the typing checks still pass, so it doesn't dig deeper. As for "Why does `class HasT(Generic[T], Protocol):` work?" that's an interesting question. I can tell you what the end result is (at runtime, it behaves as if you inherited solely from `Protocol`), but the why is a little unclear (my assumption is that something hidden in `Protocol`metaclass hierarchy is performing this twiddling before it reaches the point where MRO consistency is checked).

Comment: Or never mind. It's `Generic[T]` specifically that allows this to work. For some reason, the `_GenericAlias` class (which is the type of all parameterized generics) has a special case for `Generic` itself, where, if the set of `bases` provided to its `__mro_entries__` method (a method which is used to optionally replace the type specified for inheritance with 0-n replacement classes) include `Protocol`, it returns the empty `tuple` (deleting the explicit inheritance from `Generic[T]`, knowing that `Protocol` will provide it anyway).

Comment: Because it's only `_GenericAlias` that does this, your `class HasT(Generic[T], Protocol):` works because `Protocol` was directly inherited (doesn't check anything but direct bases) *and* you parameterized `Generic` to `Generic[T]`. Amusingly, this design means you can bypass this check by explicitly inheriting from `Protocol` as well, `class MyClass(Generic[T], Mixin, Protocol):` (won't be told about inconsistent method resolution; `Generic` is deleted before the check), but `Protocol`'s `__init_subclass__` will raise a separate error about only being allowed to inherit other protocols. Fun.

Comment: I will say, as written, you're asking three different questions: 1) "Why does this happen?" (Duplicates cover it), 2) "Why does `mypy` not catch invalid inheritance?" (Probable answer: Because it doesn't, make a feature request if you like), 3) (Not explicitly asked, but implicit in mentioning it) "Why doesn't `class HasT(Generic[T], Protocol):` have the problem?" (addressed in comments here for fun, but that one special-case works isn't really important; it only applies to those two specific classes, and you can't hook it to work with other classes, so it's not useful to answer, just fun)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the details! If you post them as an actual answer I will accept it (and potentially make the implicit question more explicit in the original so that it matches)

Comment: @ShadowRanger "you can't hook it to work with other classes" - why not, actually? I can redefine `__mro_entries__` in similar way - it will be extremely confusing, but valid!

Comment: @SUTerliakov: You can write your own set of classes that interoperate the same way. But you can't make it interoperate with the existing classes properly, because `__mro_entries__` is asking each parent class "What class(es) should I replace you with?" (and they're slotted into the original order, they can't reorder the parents). If you wrote your own class, all it could do is say "Remove *me* from the bases", it can't say "If there is a `Generic[T]` before me, remove that, because I know I'm a `Generic[T]` myself".

Comment: Basically, the hack here relies on a base class (`Generic[T]`) hardcoding knowledge of specific derived class(es) (`Protocol`) so it can gracefully delete itself when a user inherits from both of them in the wrong order. But you can only do it if you "own" the base *and* derived classes being inherited from, which for built-ins, you don't. This special case likely exists because `Protocol`, while it can be `Generic`, need not be, and it's nice to let child classes be `Generic[T]` on something unrelated to the `Protocol` for typing purposes without forcing specific inheritance order.

Comment: The problem of course being that for cases where those parent classes have meaningful behavior (neither `Generic` nor `Protocol` do), you're silently changing the behavior. If the user says they want to derive first from `A`, then from `B` (declared as `class B(A):`), yet when they call a method that's on both, it silently goes to `B` first (because `class C(A, B):` was silently treated as `class C(B):`), at best you've accepted bad code and it worked the way they wanted by coincidence (where an error would prompt them to change to `class C(B):`), at worst they have an impossible to find bug.